# Populate a gridview with Object

Tags: asp.net, class, oop, gridview

I create a class with 3 parameters so as to populate and display a gridview.
this object is composed like this : string, string, list.
I managed to display the first and the second parameter, but not the third one, like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEhda.jpg)

This is my main code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Process principal
        try
        {
            // Requête en chaînes de caractères qui sera utilisée pour récupérer les données dans la table Template
            string request = "SELECT Id, Name, Content From Template";
            // Connexion à la base de données et à la table et utilisation de la requêtes SQL
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(request, connect);
            connect.Open();

            // Exécution de la requête SQL
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // Si la commande comporte des lignes
            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                Liste_template = new List<TemplateObject>();

                // Tant que le DataReader lit des informations.
                while(sdr.Read())
                {
                    string temp_name = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                    string temp_id = sdr["Id"].ToString();                        
                    TemplateObject newTemplate = new TemplateObject(temp_id, temp_name, liste_id_form("Content", sdr));
                    Liste_template.Add(newTemplate);
                }
            }
            gv.DataSource = Liste_template;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }

    }



    // Méthode pour délimiter chaque chaque chaine de caractères à partir des symboles dans le tableau delimiterChars.
    public string[] RecupChaines(string chaine)
    {
        char[] delimiterChars = { ';', '&', '=', '"' };

        string[] words = chaine.Split(delimiterChars);

        return words;
    }

    // Méthode de récupération des Id des Form dans le champs Content de la table Template.
    public List<String> liste_id_form(string field, SqlDataReader sdr)
    {
        List<string> listIdForm = new List<string>();
        // enregistrement du contenu du champs Content dans une variable
        string content = sdr[field].ToString();

        // Tentative de séparation des deux parties de la chaine de caracteres
        string chaineACouper = "<Property Name=\"Description\" Value=\"\" />";
        string[] chaineArrive = content.Split(new string[] { chaineACouper }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        chaineArrive[0] += chaineACouper;

        // Séparation des deux parties.
        string stringPartOne = chaineArrive[0];
        string stringPartTwo = chaineArrive[1];

        // Récuperation de la liste des valeurs des FormId de la chaine de caractères
        string[] words = RecupChaines(stringPartTwo);

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].Equals("FormId"))
            {
                listIdForm.Add(words[i + 5]);
            }
        }

        return listIdForm;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to loop on list_id_form, so as to display it on my gridview. For information, my class has an id, a name, and a list of datas.
I have to work with strings, because the datas from the database is not correctly stored. I don't have hand on this and i can't modify this.

Comment: As any list you need to access it by an index. Just binding it to a gridview won't work, the gridview does not know which item you want to display from that list.

Comment: @VDWWD, so, i can't use a list in my class ? i have to use simple string ?

Comment: Either that, or get an item from the list in the ItemTemplate of the GridView

Comment: @VDWWD : How can i do that ?